# Multiple Footnotes for Multiple Figures in LaTeX

Tags: latex, tex

I have two images next to each other. The source of these images should be in the footnotes.

So far I got this:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{images/Oculus_Rift.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=6.5cm]{images/Oculus_Rift_Controller.jpg}    
\caption[Oculus Rift]{Oculus Rift\footnotemark (links) und Oculus Touch\footnotemark (rechts)}
\label{img:oculusrift}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Oculus-Rift-CV1-Headset-Front.jpg}
\footnotetext{https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Oculus-Rift-Touch-Controllers-Pair.jpg}
```

However the footnote numbers are not correct

[image]

[image]

As you can see there are two 3s instead of one 2 and one 3.

What should I do to solve this?